# What is the general form of linear operators on continuous functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, operator-theory, integral-operators

I was wondering if there was a representation for a set of operators dense
in the space of linear operators $B$ mapping $C(a,b) \to C(c,d)$. I
thought that maybe integral operators give a general representation; that is
given the right $E(u,t)$, $$\int f(t)E(u,t) dt$$ approximates an
arbitrary linear, bounded operator $T$ resulting in $$\int
f(t)E(u,t) dt = (Tf)(u)$$

I am honestly very new to operator theory and I am really clueless as to
whether or not a general representation exists. I would very much appreciate it
if someone could guide me in the right direction.

Comment: You have to specify norm on space of functions.

Comment: @user167762 Could you provide me with an example?

Comment: The sup norm is the standard norm on the space of continuous functions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_functions_on_a_compact_Hausdorff_space

Comment: Sup norm can be defined for any compact Hausdorff space. But this question is about integrals. Would not it be more natural to consider $\sqrt{ \int_{a}^{b} f^2 }$

Comment: No, the space of continuous functions is incomplete in $L^2$ norm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, more or less. Ordinary integrals do not give a general representation of bounded operators between spaces of continuous functions, the identity operator on $C(a,b)$ is not of this form, at least if you want $E(u,t)$ to actually be a function. However, there is the [Schwartz kernel theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_kernel_theorem) that represents every operator on the space of test functions (infinitely smooth of compact support) in the integral form if the kernels $E(u,t)$ are allowed to be distributions. Since test functions are continuous any operator on continuous functions has to be representable in this form as well.

For the example above of the identity operator the kernel is then $E(u,t):=\delta(u-t)$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac's delta function. Of course, not all distributional kernels define bounded operators on continuous functions, only those that are distributional densities of [signed Borel measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_measure) do. An equivalent alternative representation in terms of Stieltjes integrals $\int f(t)dK(u,t)$ is given in [Tucker's paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-05/S0002-9939-1965-0199722-9/S0002-9939-1965-0199722-9.pdf), but it is rather abstract and technical. Linear Operators by Dunford and Schwartz may have a more accessible version.

As for density and approximation, it depends in what sense. Distributions can be approximated by continuous and even by test functions in some weak senses, so this will give you approximation of bounded operators by integral ones with "ordinary" kernels in those senses. But by norm the identity operator on $C(a,b)$ can not be approximated by integral operators with say continuous kernels, because such operators are compact, and the identity is not.

Answer (score 5):

Every linear functional $x^{\star}$ on $C[a,b]$ has the form
$$
               x^{\star}(f) = \int_{a}^{b}f(t)\,d\mu(t)
$$
for a unique finite complex Borel measure $\mu$ on $[a,b]$. Furthermore,
$$
                               \|x^{\star}\| = \|\mu\|,
$$
where $\|\mu\|$ is the total variation of $\mu$ on $[a,b]$.
If $K : C[a,b]\rightarrow C[a,b]$ is a bounded linear operator, then, for each $t \in [a,b]$, let $\delta_{t}^{\star}$ be the evaluation functional at $t$. That is, $\delta_{t}^{\star}(f)=f(t)$. The functional $\delta_{t}^{\star}$ is bounded on $C[a,b]$. So $\delta_{t}^{\star}\circ K=K^{\star}\delta_{t}^{\star}$ is a bounded linear functional on $C[a,b]$. Hence, there is unique finite complex Borel measure $\mu_{t}$ such that
$$
               (Kf)(t)= \delta_{t}^{\star}(Kf) = (K^{\star}\delta_{t}^{\star})(f)=\int_{a}^{b}f(s)d\mu_{t}(s),\\
                    \|\mu_{t}\|=\|K^{\star}x_{t}^{\star}\|.
$$
If there is a dominating positive finite meausre $\mu$ such that $\mu_{t} << \mu$ for all $t\in[a,b]$, then you can write $d\mu_{t}(s) = K_{t}(s)d\mu(s)$ where $K_{t}(s) \in L^{1}_{\mu}[a,b]$ for each $t$. That gets you close to such a representation, under the additional assumption:
$$
          Kf = \int_{a}^{b}f(s)K_{t}(s)\,d\mu(s) = \int_{a}^{b}f(s)K(t,s)\,d\mu(s).
$$
Without the additional assumption, the integrals of continuous functions with respect to finite complex Borel measures can be expressed in terms of functions of bounded variation, which gives a representation as a Riemann-Stieltjes integral
$$
          Kf = \int_{a}^{b}f(s)d_{s}L_{t}(s)=\int_{a}^{b}f(s)d_{s}L(t,s).
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Really helpful

Comment: @MadcowD : You're welcome.

Comment: Why does $\delta^\star\circ K = K^\star\delta^\star$? I am confused, why should $K$ become $K^\star$, what is $K^\star$ and what is the purpose of your $*$ notation?

Comment: @MadcowD : Very often people will put $^{\star}$ after something to indicate that the object being defined is in the dual space. $\delta^{\star}_{t}$ is a bounded linear functional on $C[a,b]$ defined by $\delta^{\star}_{t}(f)=f(t)$. The operator $K^{\star}$ is defined from $K$ by $K^{\star}x^{\star}=x^{\star}\circ K$. In other words, $K^{\star}$ maps a bounded linear functional $x^{\star}$ to another bounded linear functional $K^{\star}x^{\star}$ defined by $(K^{\star}x^{\star})(x)=x^{\star}(Kx)$. This is the dual map.

Comment: @MadcowD : Yes, basically.